# How I read XLMS file row by row after a condition?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, vba

I have a problem with a XLSM Excel of which I want to get some data by condition.

[Excel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N2W0.png)

In the picture I have "Name", and "Status", if the status is "Completed" I want to take their value on "Time Assembly -> Post Assembly" where the value is "1.11". For each value of "Time Assembly" in the end I want to do media.

my code:

```
If FileUpload1.HasFile = False Then


            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim FileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
            'Dim FolderPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Upload")

            Dim FilePath As String = Server.MapPath("~") & "\Upload\" & FileName
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath)

            Dim existingFile = New FileInfo(FilePath)
            Dim pack As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(existingFile)
            Dim workBook As ExcelWorkbook = pack.Workbook

            If workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0 Then
                Dim currentWorksheet As ExcelWorksheet = workBook.Worksheets.First()


            End If

        End If
```

In that "if" I want to read Excel row by row, after that condition.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I really don't understand your question clearly. May be I am not smart enough but I can give you a tip that you can work with Excel files just like you would do with database. If you use `Microsoft.Ace.OleDb` provider, you would be able to select your rows just like you do it in the RDBMS, i.e. database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the last row in the sheet and use for loop to iterate the condition

```
Sub test()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim workBook As workBook

workBook = ThisWorkbook

lastRow = workBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastRow
             'for checking value in the 4 column(D column)
        If (workBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value) = "completed" Then
            workBook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = "xx"

        End If
                'for adding value in the 6 column
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: xlUp at me is the name of file?

Comment: xlUp is not the name of the file. XlUp is used to find the last row in a column,

Comment: lastRow = currentWorksheet.Cells(lastRow, "A").End(xlUp).Row does't work

Comment: I have error at xlUp and my vb.net does't find Rows.Count in lastRow

Comment: I have used active sheet and Column A for checking the last row. You can the column for B as well as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot @newjenn